# Java error when conect docummentdb (mongo) using SSL (jks + truststore) - docker-compose

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, docker-compose, truststore

I have a Java environment (SpringBoot) running on docker-compose where I deploy on ec2 (aws). I have configured my database in Docummentdb (aws), it already runs in lambda and connects normally using SSL connection (JKS-TrustStore), however when trying to connect using the ec2 container, it is showing the following errors:

> 2020-10-13 00:28:11.534  INFO 6 --- [onaws.com:27017]
> org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread
> while connecting to server
> CONNECTION.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
>
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:551)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:433)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:273)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:257)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:645)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:716)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:969)
> ~[na:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  at
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:430)
> ~[mongo-java-driver-3.12.7.jar!/:na]  ... 9 common frames omitted
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path
> building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:629)
> ~[na:na]  ... 23 common frames omitted Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target     at
> java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
> ~[na:na]  ... 29 common frames omitted

The same files used in the test lambda connection, are also being used in the main connection of my application, even after passing the full path of the .jks file, the error persists.

Comment: up guys, can help-me?

Answer (score 0):

try to debug with **-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake** you will have more info.

Check certificat chain, may be the validation is more restrictive on ec2 container ?

What's the setting of the **keystore.type** parameter in both lambda and ec2 **java.security** file ?